# La Madame- Who am I?

Tags: riddle, rhyme

## La madame

> I'm originally from France
> But I never really stayed there
> You can find me in Las Vegas
> You can find me in Times Square
> I have my own private island
> Though I really am not that shy
> I even let people visit
> But do you know: Who am I?

### Hints

Hint 1:

> I've aged very little, but I've changed so much.

Hint 2:

> Some may say that I have thin skin, but I am not hurt by any insults.

Hint 3:

> I'm imitated by many, though the impostors just don't size up.

Hint 4:

> In fact, the impostors simply don't hold a torch to me.

Hint 5:

> I wear a crown, yet I am not royalty.

Comment: This is my first question; feel free to critique it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, it was a good riddle. I'd like to make a note that [you should not add hints directly](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/5005/when-should-i-add-hints-to-my-puzzle) but wait for someone to solve it :)

Comment: @ABcDexter So only add hints if it's been unsolved for a while? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Lady Liberty?

La madame

I'm originally from France

> Liberty was built there

But I never really stayed there

> But she went to the States

You can find me in Las Vegas
You can find me in Times Square

> Imitation?

I have my own private island

> It's basically the only thing there

Though I really am not that shy
I even let people visit

> Lots of people come

But do you know: Who am I?

> I think I do. :P

**Hints**

Hint One:

> I've aged very little, but I've changed so much.
>  Orange --> Green

Hint Two:

> Some may say that I have thin skin, but I am not hurt by any insults.
> The copper is thin

Hint Three:

> I'm imitated by many, though the impostors just don't size up.
> Most imitations are not that big

Hint Four:

> In fact, the impostors simply don't hold a torch to me.
> She holds a torch

Hint Five:

> I wear a crown, yet I am not royalty.
>  She wears a seven-pointed crown